# PHP Array Json encode

Tags: php

With this code:

```
$array = array(
    "value" => 1,
    "secondvalue" => 2);

echo json_encode($array);
```

It prints:

> {"value":1,"secondvalue":2}

But I wan't:

> ["value", 1], ["secondvalue", 3]

I've tried json_encode($array, JSON_HEX_TAG); but same. Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Why do you even need this?

Comment: @u_mulder https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart I need add data to charts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to do

```
$array = array(
    array("value", 1),
    array("secondvalue", 2)
);

echo json_encode($array);
```

This will give you:

> [["value",1],["secondvalue",2]]

Note that the outer element is also an array, as you have to have some root element (after all it is considered ***one*** value)

**Edit:**

If you actually need it without the outer array, even though I can not image why, you could do something like this:

```
$array = array(
    array("value", 1),
    array("secondvalue", 2)
);

echo substr(json_encode($array), 1, -1);
```

Comment: [{"value":1},{"secondvalue":2}]

Comment: It prints `[["value",1],["secondvalue",2]]`, but I need `["value", 1], ["secondvalue", 3]` (without first and last **[ ]**)

Comment: @sinaza ehm.. no? the array elements are arrays too, so it is like I posted.

Comment: EvaldasL: then it's not valid json but a series of valid json snipplets.

Comment: @EvaldasL What you are wanting is several arrays, you will have to extract them then. This is not considered one value and can not be done with one call to `json_encode()`

Comment: What you want is not a valid json

Comment: @ArSeN I used 3v4l.org and that was the output :)

Comment: Thanks so much, all was ok

Comment: @EvaldasL I updated my post, in case you REALLY need it without the outer array. But please remember, I do not see a valid use case for this (as my co-commentors here seem to do too) :)

Comment: @ArSeN : You could simplify that to `echo substr(json_encode($array), 1, -1);` - gets rid of one iteration of json_encode()

Comment: @VolkerK Of course, just did, what was I thinking ... thanks for the hint :) - EvaldasL, you are welcome to hit accept if it helped you.

Comment: Emm but one question: my original code is this: `$arr = array_combine($labels, $registrations);` I need foreach or what to do that? I'm newbie in PHP :(

Comment: @EvaldasL foreach would be a viable solution then, yes.

Comment: @ArSeN can you write foreach code? :C Because I will write it two days.. :D

Comment: Or skip the array_combine and use a [MultipleIterator](http://docs.php.net/multipleIterator) instead ;-)